# spring boot JPQL with like operator issue with MySQL when column supports unicode characters

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpql, sql-like

When i am using like operator with jpql and search column data type has `utf8mb4`
then if i use one emoji  to search record. it selects all records which contains any emoji.

so, how can we make search only for particular emoji